# How do I loop through merged cells in a faster way

Tags: excel, vba

I have merged cells in my sheet "interspersed" and not in any pattern.
I need to replace the blank merged cells with "-"; dash.

**Is there a faster way than this**:

```
Sub ReplaceblankMergedCells()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim startcolumn, endcolumn, startrow, endrow As Long
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If c.MergeCells Then
            If c.Value = "" Then
                c.Value = "_"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could break up the entire range to check in chunks, and check if each of these chunks contains merged cells.  In the case of this being false, you won't have to check each cell in such a chunk, thereby saving time. How much time you would save, if any, would vary on your setup and the amount of chunks you specify.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceblankMergedCells()
Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim startcolumn As Long, endcolumn As Long, startrow As Long, endrow As Long
Dim totalchunks As Integer, chunkcols As Integer, i As Integer

With Sheet2 'Edit

    startcolumn = 1
    endcolumn = 50
    startrow = 2
    endrow = 1000
    totalchunks = 10 'set amount of chunks
    chunkcols = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((endcolumn - startcolumn + 1) / totalchunks , 0) '10 chunks of 5 columns

    For i = startcolumn To endcolumn Step chunkcols
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(startrow, i), .Cells(endrow, i + chunkcols - 1))

        'Prevent the loop from overshooting the last column
        If i + chunkcols - 1 > endcolumn Then Set r = .Range(.Cells(startrow, i), .Cells(endrow, endcolumn))
        'check if the chunk contains merged cells
        If IsNull(r.MergeCells) = True Or r.MergeCells = True Then
            'If it does contain merged cells, loop through the chunk
            For Each c In r
                If c.MergeCells And c.Value = "" Then c.Value = "_"
            Next c
        End If
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```

As you can (hopefully) tell, I have divided the set range by ten. This breaks up the range in 10 equal parts of 5 rows, in case of the total amount of columns in the range being 50.

I advise you to play around with how large these chunks should be. You could also break up the chunks in more chunks horizontally, say half the rows in one sub-chunk and the other half in another sub-chunk.

Comment: @isomericharsh Have you found your answer?

Comment: Not yet, but will be revisiting the problem, while optimising the code. WIll keep posted.

Comment: Good luck, let me know. Speeding up data processing can get quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your worksheet or change the determination of the sheet and see if this does it for you ...

```
Public Sub ReplaceMergeCellsWithHyphen()
    Dim objCells As Range, objCell As Range, objDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim strRange As String, objSheet As Worksheet

    Set objSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set objCells = objSheet.Range("A1:" & objSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)

    For Each objCell In objCells
        If objCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            If Not objDict.Exists(objCell.MergeArea.Address) Then objDict.Add objCell.MergeArea.Address, ""
        End If
    Next

    With objSheet
        For i = 0 To objDict.Count - 1
            strRange = objDict.Keys(i)

            If .Range(strRange).Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
                .Range(strRange).Cells(1, 1).Value = "-"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It may be a bit hard to see in the image but after running the macro, the merged cells that do not have a value are filled with a hyphen.

Not sure if it's necessary faster but it works and (I think) is fairly robust.

[image]